# Delphi 10.3.3 fails macOS notarization

Tags: macos, delphi, deployment

My program was being notarized in Delphi 10.3.2, but fails in 10.3.3. PAClient exits with code 1. Is there a log that will help me diagnose the problem? If so, how do I find it?

Here is the whole error afterward:

```
    Connecting to 192.168.1.231 on port 64211... 
    Status Code: 2, LogFileURL: 
    c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(581,5): error MSB6006: "paclient" exited with code 1.
Done building target "_OSXDeveloperID" in project "MintToReport4.dproj" -- FAILED.
Done building project "MintToReport4.dproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(581,5): error MSB6006: "paclient" exited with code 1.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Comment: Make sure PAServer is in verbose mode (v command) and thet you also check the Output tab of the messages window

Comment: Thanks. I am getting a paclient exitcode 1. The output shows also error MSB6006. Just have to figure out why I am getting that.

Comment: Just "error M"? There should be way more

Comment: I just edited my post. I thought since I was going off topic a new post would be better

Comment: It's showing a status code of 2, which means there's a configuration issue for your app. Please check that you've followed all steps, using this as a guide: https://www.delphiworlds.com/2019/07/notarizing-your-macos-64-bit-apps-built-with-delphi/

Comment: Also, it seems odd that the LogFileURL is missing. If it actually has one, you can use it to discover the details of the problem, as indicated here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow?language=objc (search for LogFileURL on that page)

Comment: Thanks, Dave. All my configuration looks fine. Pulled automatically from 10.3.2. I wish there was a log also. The same application was notarized fine in 10.3.2.

Comment: So, LogFileURL (that appears after Status Code: 2) really is blank?

Comment: Yes, no log file. Is that an option somewhere?

Comment: I did not mean that it is an option, just that your output shows "Connecting to 192.168.1.231 on port 64211... Status Code: 2, LogFileURL:" with nothing after it. A url to the logfile should be there.

Comment: No, it isn't. It is blank just as displayed above. No URL is given. Just blank.