# Delphi 10.3.3 macOS Notarization, error paclient exit code 1

Tags: macos, delphi, deployment, notarize

I have seen questions about this error with Android and IOS, but I am getting this error trying to notarize my macOS 64-bit app. I don't see any other details so I don't know where to start. I didn't get this error in 10.3.2. Any suggestions?

Comment: Already suggested on your original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61292906/delphi-10-3-3-fails-macos-notarization

Comment: Do not post a new question about the same topic when you've already asked it before. If you're not getting answers, edit the question to improve it to see if that helps. Posting a duplicate is inappropriate.